# How can I always show the mouse pointer on a touchscreen laptop?

Tags: mouse, touchscreen, cursor, gsettings, mouse-pointer

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, and when I touch the screen, the mouse pointer disappears until I use the trackpad to move it outside the current window. I'd prefer to have the pointer visible at all times, even while using the touchscreen. Is there a setting that would force the mouse cursor to always show?

Comment: Shame you didn't get a response to this. I'd like to do this too - because sometimes the cursor doesn't come back after using the touch screen.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if Wayland is enabled, if it is false, please enable it.

It seems that on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS upgrade from 20.04 it disabled Wayland and reverted to x11.

1. We will edit the /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file

`sudo vim /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

2. Within this file, look for the line that says #WaylandEnable=false.

`WaylandEnable=true`

3. Restart GDM3 or reboot

`sudo systemctl restart gdm3`

WARNING: you will be logged out, so you need to login
i can confirm this method as for me it worked

Reference:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop

Please give me reputation that i am able to start also commenting :)

Thank you for your time reading

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I still have to move the pointer to see it after a touchscreen tap, but at least now I don't have to move it all the way out of the window.

Comment: Unluckily I needed to switch back to `WaylandEnable=false` because I had other issues with Remmina and especially with flameshot for screenshots. flameshot does NOT work with Wayland and i need flameshot for my job :)