# How to show mouse pointer on a touched location?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, touchscreen

I am using Ubuntu22.04 with a touchscreen.

By default, the mouse pointer is displayed when the user operates the mouse, but nothing is displayed when the user touches the touchscreen.

Is it possible to display a screen where the user can always see where they touch?

I tried this post. But it is not a solution for me.
[How can I always show the mouse pointer on a touchscreen laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405363/how-can-i-always-show-the-mouse-pointer-on-a-touchscreen-laptop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Install gnome extension "Touch X".
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6156/touch-x/